# Almost `docker pull` command hanging - retry(after 5min) - complete

Tags: docker, timeout, pull

```
$ docker pull python:3.6.4-stretch
3.6.4-stretch: Pulling from library/python
c73ab1c6897b: Pull complete
1ab373b3deae: Downloading [=============================================>     ]  10.13MB/11.11MB
b542772b4177: Download complete
57c8de432dbe: Download complete
1ab373b3deae: Pull complete
b542772b4177: Pull complete
57c8de432dbe: Pull complete
1785850988c5: Pull complete
676ef2d8682b: Pull complete
56321bcc2d38: Pull complete
4788c366a216: Pull complete
0d970fbfeb26: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:db22cb78ba16cb6a0632eead1e48a239636a5a77c9f8cf343087acf309ad0248
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.6.4-stretch
Time: 0h:05m:33s
```

Download hangs with a probability of 80% or more like above ouput. Then hold this state for 5 minutes and pull will succeed when retry starts.

For more detail, this problem occurs in three ubuntu pc.
Two are Ubuntu 16.04 and one is 18.04. All machine are on the same office network.

At first I tried changing the docker and ubuntu versions but it failed. `service docker restart` was also useless. I noticed that I installed a new gigabit switch hub(https://iptime.com/iptime/?page_id=11&pf=12&page=2&pt=311&pd=1), and I suspected the hub device. It works well when machine connects directly to the LAN without a switching hub and When I changed the switching hub to the old 100Mb/s thing, it worked well also.

It can be judged as a problem of the gigabit switching hub, but it is difficult to find out because all other internet use is work well with gigabit switching hub. So I wonder if there is no other problem with docker pull or there is no other solution.

```
$ uname -a
Linux my-ubuntu18.04 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:48:57 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.0
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       4d60db4
  Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:16:44 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Please search `failed` keyword in below my docker daemon log.

```
12:13:32 level=debug msg="Calling GET /_ping"
12:13:32 level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.39/info"
12:13:32 level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.39/images/create?fromImage=python&tag=3.6.6-stretch"
12:13:32 level=debug msg="Trying to pull python from https://registry-1.docker.io v2"
12:13:35 level=debug msg="Pulling ref from V2 registry: python:3.6.6-stretch"
12:13:35 level=debug msg="docker.io/library/python:3.6.6-stretch resolved to a manifestList object with 7 entries; looking for a unknown/amd64 match"
12:13:35 level=debug msg="found match for linux/amd64 with media type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, digest sha256:c306863aa2e858ccf00958c625ca2ffdbf8845da76e266b0b0d9c4760170aff3"
12:13:36 level=debug msg="Layer already exists: bc9ab73e5b14"
12:13:36 level=debug msg="Layer already exists: 193a6306c92a"
12:13:36 level=debug msg="Layer already exists: e5c3f8c317dc"
12:13:36 level=debug msg="Layer already exists: a587a86c9dcb"
12:13:36 level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:72744d0a318b0788001cc4f5f83c6847ba4b753307fadd046b508bbc41eb9e29\""
12:13:36 level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:6598fc9d11d10365ac9281071a87930a2382ee31d026f1b6d432717b31db387c\""
12:13:37 level=debug msg="Downloaded 6598fc9d11d1 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob402585872"
12:13:37 level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:4b1d9004d467b4e710d770a881df027df7e5e7e4629f6e473760893ffc1a667f\""
12:13:40 level=debug msg="Downloaded 72744d0a318b to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob083083061"
12:13:40 level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:93612f47cdc374d0b33057b9e71eac173ac469da3e1a631dc8a32ba6986a408a\""
12:13:40 level=debug msg="Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9eaab31d9a1f108ba8a5c712cf23f36a9097140d09c76e6b966667fba2cc014b/diff" storage-driver=overlay2
12:13:42 level=debug msg="Downloaded 93612f47cdc3 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob281534658"
12:13:42 level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:1bc4b4b508703799ef67a807dacce4736045e642e87bcd49871cd0f23e7f5b8b\""
12:13:43 level=debug msg="Downloaded 1bc4b4b50870 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob872144708"
12:13:48 level=debug msg="Applied tar sha256:9978d084fd771e0b3d1acd7f3525d1b25288ababe9ad8ed259b36101e4e3addd to 9eaab31d9a1f108ba8a5c712cf23f36a9097140d09c76e6b966667fba2cc014b, size: 556457027"
12:13:48 level=debug msg="Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3f91f78b3bb3f2cb6096472759bb84ae2f30f0825a7f935cad3b420c5cd71bee/diff" storage-driver=overlay2
12:13:48 level=debug msg="Applied tar sha256:2f4f74d3821ecbdd60b5d932452ea9e30cecf902334165c4a19837f6ee636377 to 3f91f78b3bb3f2cb6096472759bb84ae2f30f0825a7f935cad3b420c5cd71bee, size: 16849952"
12:18:46 level=error msg="Download failed, retrying: read tcp 10.251.12.218:48728->104.18.121.25:443: read: connection timed out"
12:18:51 level=debug msg="pulling blob \"sha256:4b1d9004d467b4e710d770a881df027df7e5e7e4629f6e473760893ffc1a667f\""
12:18:51 level=debug msg="attempting to resume download of \"sha256:4b1d9004d467b4e710d770a881df027df7e5e7e4629f6e473760893ffc1a667f\" from 20499209 bytes"
12:18:53 level=debug msg="Downloaded 4b1d9004d467 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob954105135"
12:18:53 level=debug msg="Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/458b54b72a80967b2ba5dfca870ed5de222677fc98910538674fbf15ce958dda/diff" storage-driver=overlay2
12:18:54 level=debug msg="Applied tar sha256:003bb6178bc3218242d73e51d5e9ab2f991dc607780194719c6bd4c8c412fe8c to 458b54b72a80967b2ba5dfca870ed5de222677fc98910538674fbf15ce958dda, size: 65191894"
12:18:54 level=debug msg="Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f4a3bdc5aa6c4428d3368143b0b26c92dd19e12c7c536d20a95a3fdc8a221d3/diff" storage-driver=overlay2
12:18:54 level=debug msg="Applied tar sha256:15b32d849da2239b1af583f9381c7a75d7aceba12f5ddfffa7a059116cf05ab9 to 0f4a3bdc5aa6c4428d3368143b0b26c92dd19e12c7c536d20a95a3fdc8a221d3, size: 32"
12:18:54 level=debug msg="Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c7905eabea23cd147b6772ce255d536b0cdcb759d4387b8282259b338d392c34/diff" storage-driver=overlay2
12:18:54 level=debug msg="Applied tar sha256:6e5c5f6bf043bc634378b1e4b61af09be74741f2ac80204d7a373713b1fd5a40 to c7905eabea23cd147b6772ce255d536b0cdcb759d4387b8282259b338d392c34, size: 5918893"
```

Comment: If I test with a other model gigabit switching hub, I will share it here.

Comment: The problem still occurs with a gigabit switching hub from another manufacturer. Therefore, it is not a problem of a specific switching hub.